# Center textbox with unknown size and scrollbar vertically and horizontally in Safari (MacOS and iOS)

Tags: html, css, safari, mobile-safari, centering

I am trying to center a text-box to get the below behavior (the text varies in size). If height of browser is small enough, a scrollbar should be visible in the box. This works fine in Chrome, IE and FireFox but not in Safari (both iOS and MacOS). Any ideas how to get this to work in the "Apple" world?

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#test {
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #fff;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}

#sumup {
  background-color: #123456;
  max-width: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 30px;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div id="sumup">
 <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
 <div id="date">Why doesn't this work in safari? Lorem ipsum dolor ... [longer text] ... vestibulum diam.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/xerbnuq1/

1.The text box with large browser height

2.The text box with smaller browser height

3.Safari behaviour (older PC version) Also newer versions of Safari handles this wrong on Mac and iPhone

[image: the text box with large browser height]
[image: the text box with smaller browser height]
[image: Safari behaviour (older PC version) Also newer versions of Safari handles this wrong on Mac and iPhone]

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with this:

```css
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  
}

#test {
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  display:-webkit-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #fff;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}

#sumup {
  background-color: #123456;
  max-width: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 30px;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div id="sumup">
    <h1 class="titre">Title</h1>
    <div id="date">Why doesn't this work in safari? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean mauris libero, vestibulum eget ligula vel, tincidunt tempor erat. Maecenas at dolor non felis porta molestie et vitae nulla. Morbi aliquet ornare mi, eu blandit libero suscipit sit amet. Donec dolor ante, tempor a est ut, egestas vestibulum diam.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

you should use `-webkit` prefix for webkit browsers like safari.

In your case, `display:-webkit-flex`

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xerbnuq1/3/)